# How to format javascript code with html for a count up timer?

Tags: javascript, html

Hello stackoverflow community. My first question :D

I'm trying to put a simple javascript code on my site that counts up, showing how long a visitor has been on that page. When refreshed it will reset and start counting up again. I took inspiration from https://thevegancalculator.com/animal-slaughter/ where it shows in red: *It has been xx minutes and xx seconds.* I have the basic js code but need some help in tidying it up and the right html to format it, so it looks like the one on the site. This is what I have so far.

```
var sec =0, min=0, hour=0;
setInterval(function(){
    sec++;
    if(sec==60){sec=0; min++;}
    if(min==60){min=0; hour++;}
    var str = 'It has been';
    str+= hour?' ' +hour + (hour==1?' hour':' hours') + ' and':'';
    str+= min?' ' +min+ (min==1?' minute':' minutes') + ' and':'';
    str+= sec?' ' +sec+ (sec==1?' second':' seconds'):'';
document.getElementById('passed').innerHTML=str;
},1000);
```

Here's a link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vdgyx67z/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the HTML and CSS like so:

HTML:

```
<div id="passed"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#passed{
  color: #e11 !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: oxygen, sans-serif;
}
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ov9hLs8/